# Coldfusion thumb nail

Tags: coldfusion, thumbnails

How can i create a thumbnail in `coldfusion` based on `cfcomponent` who stores html code?

i know that `coldfusion` can easily convert html code to pdf (cause its a native) and then put it in a thumbnail but i guess this action hit directly in the performance and the same way i cant store images on a DB cause the html will be create dynamically based on the html code and then will have a thumbnail preview of this rendered html, there is other way to do that?

Comment: Do you want a thumbnail of an image, or of html output, or both?

Comment: the source is a html, but the output thumbnail not matter if is an image o html

Comment: Basically what you want is something that will reach out and get html, parse it, render it like a browser and then generate an image based on the rendered html. ????? That is quite a tall order. Are you trying to create something like : http://www.thumboo.com/ ?

Comment: [read](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/271-creating-web-site-thumbnails-using-coldfusion-and-webshot-v-1.htm)

Comment: As @JamesAMohler indicated you are going to need a third party for this. I would look for a jar file you can instantiate as a class, then pass in a URL for rendering. the CFDOCUMENT approach does 3 things - parses the HTML, renders as PDF and then creates your thumbnail - that's expensive and (due to the page constraints) not very effective.